# How do you condense multiple groups into one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

I have a simple data set for which I want to label user_ids who have ANY matching row in a left join as having 'ever' taken an action, and by extension label those who have 'never' taken an action.

I'm having trouble condensing the values resulting from GROUP BY to get a single value for each user_id if they have 'ever' taken an action.

**See rextester for sample data and query: http://rextester.com/BOVT75663**

**visits:**

```
| loc_id | user_id | site_visit_date | site_visit_count |
|--------|---------|-----------------|------------------|
| 1234   | 003     | 06/05/2016      | 1                |
| 1234   | 003     | 06/06/2016      | 1                |
| 1234   | 003     | 06/09/2016      | 1                |
| 1234   | 802     | 05/18/2016      | 1                |
| 1234   | 818     | 02/19/2016      | 1                |
| 1234   | 818     | 02/21/2016      | 1                |
...and so on
```

**actions:**

```
| loc_id | user_id | action_date | action_category | action_count |
|--------|---------|-------------|-----------------|--------------|
| 1234   | 003     | 06/05/2016  | action123       | 2            |
| 1234   | 003     | 06/14/2016  | action123       | 5            |
| 1234   | 003     | 07/01/2016  | action123       | 1            |
| 1234   | 868     | 02/29/2016  | action123       | 13           |
| 1234   | 868     | 03/17/2016  | action123       | 9            |
| 1234   | 877     | 02/08/2016  | action123       | 5            |
| 1234   | 877     | 03/25/2016  | action123       | 4            |
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
| user_id | ever_never | sum  |
|---------|------------|------|
| 3       | ever       | 7    |
| 802     | never      | NULL |
| 818     | never      | NULL |
| 868     | ever       | 22   |
| 871     | never      | NULL |
| 876     | never      | NULL |
| 877     | ever       | 9    |
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT / QUERY:**

```
| user_id | ever_never | sum  |
|---------|------------|------|
| 3       | ever       | 7    |
| 3       | never      | NULL |
| 802     | never      | NULL |
| 818     | never      | NULL |
| 868     | ever       | 22   |
| 868     | never      | NULL |
| 871     | never      | NULL |
| 876     | never      | NULL |
| 877     | ever       | 9    |
| 877     | never      | NULL |

with tbl as (
select
    v.loc_id
    ,v.user_id
    ,TO_CHAR(v.site_visit_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ,v.site_visit_count
    ,TO_CHAR(a.action_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ,a.action_category
    ,a.action_count
    ,case when a.action_count >=1 then 'ever' else 'never' end ever_never
from
    visits v
    left join actions a on v.user_id = a.user_id and v.site_visit_date = a.action_date
order by 1,2,5
)
select
    user_id
    ,ever_never
    ,sum(action_count)
from
    tbl
group by
    user_id
    ,ever_never
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Both answers suffice by using an aggregate function the select the desired min/max of the group in question. I see now that a more effective way to flag members based on the desired 'ever/never' status would be a 1/0 to ensure that min/max yield the desired numeric result as opposed to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MIN` function to select the `ever`, when there is also a `never`:

```
with tbl as (
select
   v.loc_id
   ,v.user_id
   ,TO_CHAR(v.site_visit_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
   ,v.site_visit_count
   ,TO_CHAR(a.action_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
   ,a.action_category
   ,a.action_count
   ,case when a.action_count >=1 then 'ever' else 'never' end ever_never
from
visits v
left join actions a on v.user_id = a.user_id and v.site_visit_date = a.action_date
order by 1,2,5
)
select
   user_id
   ,MIN(ever_never)
   ,sum(action_count)
from
   tbl
group by
   user_id
order by 1,2
```

Check the results: http://rextester.com/live/LQDR42614

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ever_never` from the last `group by`:

```
select user_id, min(ever_never) as ever_never, sum(action_count)
from tbl
group by user_id
order by 1
```

Comment: This is giving me a 'never' for user_ids that should be an 'ever' on the basis of their match in the left join. If I can clarify the post at all please let me know.